# Double quotes in C don't produce string, instead, they drop weird bytes into memory?

Tags: c, string

So I have a weird problem. Double quotes in C are behaving in ways I don't understand.

My situation is I'm trying to write a basic operating system, and I'm not using any libraries. I just implemented a print function, which works perfectly... if I manually build the strings.

I was under the impression that using double quotes in C simply wrote an array of characters and a null terminator. I like this explanation, it's simple and fits with my understanding of C cleanly. So you can see how I would be deeply troubled by the notion that something else was going on!

So, to illustrate:

```
  unsigned char *str = "bleah";      //doesn't work
  print_char(str[0], 2, 5, WHIT_BLK);//doesn't work
  print_at(str, 3, 4);               //doesn't work
```

but:

```
 unsigned char* msg;              
 *msg = 'n';                        
 *(msg + 1) = 'o';                  
 *(msg + 2) = 'p'; 
 *(msg + 3) = 'e';
 *(msg + 4) = 0;                    

 print_at(msg, 4, 4);               //works, but string
                                 //must be constructed
                                 //manually
```

If I do:

```
unsigned char* str;
*str = "BLAH DE BLAH BLAH";
print_at(str, 0, 0);
```

I get a strange result where seemingly random, senseless symbols get printed.

The most obvious thing I can think of is that this functionality is implemented in one of the header files I normally use, and if this is the case I will need to build such functionality itself. I'm not sure how I would go about that.

edit:

my print_at function:

```
void print_at(unsigned char* message, int row, int col){ //string must be manually created for some reason

  if (col >= 0 && row >= 0){
    int a = get_screen_offset(col, row);
    set_cursor(a);
  }

  int i=0;
  while (message[i] != '\0'){

    print_char(message[i], -1, -1, WHIT_BLK);
    i++;
  }
}
```

and here is print_char():

```
void print_char(char character, int row, int col, char attribute){

  //pointer to start of video memory
  unsigned char* vidmem = (unsigned char*) VID_ADDR;

  //default color scheme
  if (!attribute){
    attribute = WHIT_BLK;
  }

  //memory offset
  int offset; 
  // if row and col < 0, offset is cursor

  if (col >= 0 && row >= 0){
    offset = get_screen_offset(col, row);
  }
  else {
    offset = get_cursor();
  }

  if (character == '\n'){
    //new line
    int rows = offset / (2 * MAX_COLS);
    offset = get_screen_offset(79, rows);
  }
  else{
    unsigned char* locale = vidmem + offset;
    unsigned char* attr_locale = vidmem + offset + 1;
    *locale = character;
    *attr_locale = attribute;
  }

  offset += 2;
  offset = handle_scrolling(offset);
  set_cursor(offset);
}
```

I have tested print_char extensively and as long as it receives proper input it behaves properly in all cases I have tested it in, I am very confident the issue is not in this function.

Comment: posted it as an edit

Comment: `*str = "BLAH DE BLAH BLAH"` looks wrong as the dereference gives a char but you are assigning a `const char *` to it. Same with the middle section of code that starts with the `*msg ` line. Those are invalid memory accesses (no memory was allocated for `msg`) so any behaviour you get is undefined at best.

Comment: Try  `unsigned char const* str = "bleah";`

Comment: "and I know print_char() works perfectly" - if you want to be a programmer, you're going to have to realize when you say things like that and recognize that there's a very high chance you're wrong. Show us `print_char`.

Comment: Post `print_char()` as well. Something looking like it 'works perfectly' doesn't mean it actually does. For a start, your 'working' example writes straight into uninitialized memory.

Comment: using const char makes no difference. nothing is printed. *str = "BLAH DE BLAH BLAH" is wrong, but it's wrong in what I thought was potentially an interesting way, since it creates garbage characters, which I can't figure out the origin of.

Comment: what compiler are you using? what platform?

Comment: Wow, this question is a mess. `unsigned char* msg; *msg = 'n';` doesn't "work", you are writing through an uninitialized pointer.  `unsigned char* str; *str = "BLAH DE BLAH BLAH";` doesn't even compile. Please rewrite this question. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular please make sure you post the *actual code*, and also post the *actual evidence* which leads to your conclusion of "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
unsigned char *str = "bleah";
```

suffers from two problems - `const` correctness and `signed/unsigned` types.

Use of

```
char const *str1 = "bleah 1";
unsigned char str2[] = "bleah 2";
```

works with gcc 4.8.2.